# I have error as Expression must be modifiable value

Tags: c

I had code below gives error

```
#define ONE_SAMPLE    6
#define DATA_BUFF     100
int main()
{
    unsigned int total;
    for (ONE_SAMPLE=0;ONE_SAMPLE<DATA_BUFF;ONE_SAMPLE++)
    {
        total=ONE_SAMPLE*DATA_BUFF;
        i2cread(read function of sensor);
    }
}
```

for loop saying expression must be a modifiable value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `ONE_SAMPLE` to be `6`

```
#define ONE_SAMPLE    6
```

and then using incrementing that in the loop

---

When the preprocessor has done its job, the loop will look like this

```
for (6=0;6<100;6++)
{
    total=6*100;
    i2cread(read function of sensor);
}
```

The expressions `6=0` does not make any sense. It is trying to assign `0` to a constant `6`. Constants are not **assignable l-value**. That is why you are getting this error.

---